# How to make m2e (maven integration for eclipse) know where to find dependencies?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When work in STS (springsource tool suite), open pom.xml file and check dependencies in "dependencies tab", add/select maven dependency will give 0 result found.  We need edit pom.xml to add dependency by hand.  Is there a way to let M2E know where to check repository to search dependency?

Comment: Do you mean to resolve dependencies automatically (by discovering the packages+classes used for example?), without indicating Maven which dependencies to add?

Comment: The question is to ask a way to automate this: turning to browser and using some maven repository search engines , to find out the <dependency>...</dependency> xml snippets for artifacts that I want to use and then paste them in the pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M2e by default searches maven central repository for artifacts. It downloads an index file which has artifact details. You can configure additional repositories to be searched by specifying the same in *repository* section of your *settings.xml* file. Do note that some repositories do not have this index file.

Comment: Yes, and thank you.  The repository section of settings.xml file help M2E to find a index, then it can give hints when adding dependencies.  Else, it give no hint, leave you finding xml snippets all by yourself.  Although, I still not sure why I didn't get a default index.

Answer (score 3):

By default , all **pom.xml** will automatically extend the Super POM , which is located in the `maven_installation_folder/lib/maven-x.x.x-uber.jar` ==> package `org.apache.maven.project` ==> **pom-4.0.0.xml** . All the configuration specified in the Super POM is inherited by the POMs you created for your projects.

If you open   **pom-4.0.0.xml** , you will find that the maven central repository `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` is defined here  . That means  if you specify a `<dependency>` in your **pom.xml** , maven will try to download this dependency in the following orders:

1. Maven local repository (i.e your local hard disk)
2. Maven central repository specifed in the Super POM  (i.e http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
3. Maven remote repository (Defined in the `<repository>` section of  your **pom.xml** )

Normally , I will use some maven repository search engines , such as [this](http://mvnrepository.com/) , to find out the `<dependency>` of the libraries /frameworks /tools  that I want to use and then paste them in the **pom.xml**

If the dependency exists in the Maven central repository , everything will be fine and it will be download to your local  repository .  However , if some of the `<dependency>` (eg Hibernate) cannot be found and downloaded from the Maven central repository , you can try to visit  its official site to  find out its repository link and paste them in the `<repository>` section of  your **pom.xml** .For example , Hibernate require to define the jboss repository in the pom.xml like this:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
            <name>JBoss Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
           <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>     
        </repository>        
 </repositories>
```

You can refer to [this](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) for the use of `<repository>`